# LoRa RFM95/SX1276 libraries for PIC 8 bit microcontrollers

Tags: pic, library, lora

I recently finished prototyping a LoRa RFM95 transceiver with an Arduino Uno using the RadioHead RFM95 library. I am now transitioning to designing a PCB for my project and chose a PIC16F18446 microcontroller based on my other needs.

I would like to know if there is any way to make the RadioHead Library work with the PIC? If not, please point me towards how I should go about programming the PIC to talk to the RFM95/SX1276 module. Any help would be very useful.

Comment: I suggest that you ask on www.piclist.com (do NOT be put off by the arcane presentation) then visit http://mailman.mit.edu/mailman/listinfo/piclist and join the mailing list and say hello. It's likely that at least one list member will be a guru in your area of interest.  And while the list is very quiet these days there are people there who know almost everything (collectively) like here BUT unlike here you are allowed to discuss anything conversationally. Some members of this group are also PICList members (myself included).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I have joined the mailing list and sent a mail regarding my question. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing on responses:

Brent Brown said:

Can't help with RadioHead library sorry, but if you haven't seen them already
Microchip has LoRaWAN modules that incorporate a PIC18LF46K22, SX1276 radio
chip, crystals, EEPROM with ID, antenna matching networks etc. See the RN2483
(dual freq 433 & 868MHz) and RN2903 (915MHz). Cost is not too high, probably not
much more than what you can buy the individual components for, and it's in a nice
small metal shielded module.

https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RN2483
https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/RN2903

https://www.scoop.it/topic/high-temperaure-wireless/p/4071285298/2016/11/06/micr
ochip-rn2483-teardown

You can re-flash the firmware on these to run anything you like (ICSP I/O pins come
out on external pads), but they come with a pre-qualified LoRaWAN application
which could well be suitable out of the box. The source code is also published, so it
could be alternate pathway for you.

---

& Roger Morrell said:

The Radio Head library **can** be made to work with that model PIC - I did it for a specialized application. Unfortunately the work I did cannot be easily shared and I'm over committed at the moment.

I use the CCS C compiler - PICC  which is a little different than the Microchip one.
I think there is a version of the RadioHead source on the HopeRf site.